# Entity Framework 4 code-based migrations don´t work after calling CreateDatabaseIfNotExist

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations

I have a MVC 3 project were I use code based migrations together mith automatic migrations(this works).

When I install this project on a new server the database is created by CreateDatabaseIfNotExist initializer, cause I´m using the seed method of this. After executing this I have a __MigrationHistory table with one entry. The model hash of this entry is exactly the same like the last one from my developement server. On my development server I have an entry for each of my code based migration in the __MigrationHistory table.

Now the problem is that when I try to run the migrations on the new server, I expected them to say to me "nothing to do, cause model hash is same", but instead of this the migrations seems to look only for the MigrationId in the database and try to execute every migration whose MigrationId is missing. Of course this leads to Exceptions, cause the migration tries to add database structures already there.

I think this should be a very common scenario, so is there a kind of workaround for this? My workaround for the moment is to copy all contents from the __MigrationHistory of the development system to the new server, but this is very tricky, due to the dealing with the modelhash as varbinary. Is there a better solution or did I understand some logical things wrong?